# Angular 11 ng-select with ngmodel default value is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular10, angular11

Firstly Hello there

this is my code :

```
<tbody *ngIf="IsLoading">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of InComingCustomer; index as i">
       <td>
        <ng-select name="DriverID" #DriverID placeholder="Seçiniz" [clearable]="false"
          (change)="ArrivalDriverOnChange($event,item)" [(ngModel)]="item.ArrivalAirportDriverPersonelId" (
          class="custom select-operation">
          <ng-option *ngFor="let personnel of DriverList" [value]="personnel.PersonnelId">
            {{personnel.PersonnelName}}
            {{personnel.PersonnelSurname}}</ng-option>
        </ng-select>
      </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

**"item.ArrivalAirportDriverPersonelId"** works normally but does not work in ngmodel default value does not come.

but It works when I get "[(ngModel)]" value from "typescript" html code;

```
 <tbody *ngIf="IsLoading">
            <tr *ngFor="let item of InComingCustomer; index as i">
           <td>
            <ng-select name="DriverID" #DriverID placeholder="Seçiniz" [clearable]="false"
              (change)="ArrivalDriverOnChange($event,item)" [(ngModel)]="ArrivalAirportDriverPersonelId" (
              class="custom select-operation">
              <ng-option *ngFor="let personnel of DriverList" [value]="personnel.PersonnelId">
                {{personnel.PersonnelName}}
                {{personnel.PersonnelSurname}}</ng-option>
            </ng-select>
          </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
```

typescript code ;

```
  ArrivalAirportDriverPersonelId = 9;
```

is there someone to help me please ?

Comment: Can you show your `item` structure ? does `ArrivalAirportDriverPersonelId` always exists ?

Comment: Checked now it doesn't always come ,sometimes it come null

Comment: The point is `item` must have a property named `ArrivalAirportDriverPersonelId`, even if it is null. if it doesn't exist, `ngModel` cannot stick to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. What should I do? If there is no value, it comes null.

Comment: Can you show the content of InComingCustomer, and how do you retrieve it ?

Comment: i solved it thanks for help :)